# Finding the construction of universal properties

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-property

> Identify for all of the following universal properties the corresponding construction (commutative diagram) .
>   Notation: $K$  is a field, $ U $ and $ V $ are vector spaces and $ f:V\rightarrow U$ is a linear map
>
> a) Let $ W $ be a $ K$  vector space with linear map $g:V\rightarrow W$, such that $g\circ f=0$ and there exists for all $K$ vector spaces $T$ with linear
>   mapping $ h:V \rightarrow T$ and $h\circ f = 0$ a unique linear map $l:W \rightarrow T$ with $l \circ g = h.$

So this is one of many exercices our linear algebra teacher gave us to solve. I really do not understand how to attempt an exercice like this. I have very little experience with category theory but maybe you can help me with this one to solve the other ones.

Comment: something does not add up, you probably mean $f:U\to V$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full exercise could be, with $f:U\to V$ and $g:V\to W$ with the mentioned property:

> Prove that $W\cong \def\coker{V/{\,\rm im\,}f} \coker$.

For this, the easiest way is to

1. Prove that $\coker$ satisfies the given universal property.
2. Use the uniqueness criterium to prove that if $W_1$ and $W_2$ both satisfy the universal property, then $W_1\cong W_2$.

Comment: Very nice it's probably meant that way, i.e. $W$ is a cokernel of $f$ which also explains the uniqueness of $\ell$